# How to include Rails Helpers on RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, tdd, rspec2

I'm trying to include some helpers to test with rspec but no luck.

What I did:

created a `support/helpers.rb` file under my `spec` folder.

**support/helpers.rb**

```
module Helpers
  include ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper
  include ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper
end
```

and tried to require this file in `spec_helper.rb`.

```
# This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
require 'rubygems'
require 'spork'
require 'support/helpers'

Spork.prefork do
.
.
end
```

this generates the following error:

```
/spec/support/helpers.rb:2:in `<module:Helpers>': uninitialized constant Helpers::ActionView (NameError)
```

How should I do this helpers to be available with Rspec?

Thanks.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I normally include this code to require everything under my `spec/support` subdirectory once the Rails stack is available:

```
Spork.prefork do

  # ...

  Dir[Rails.root.join('spec', 'support', '**', '*.rb')].each { |f| require f }

  RSpec.configure do |config|
    config.include MyCustomHelper

    # ...
  end
end
```

Note that this will include `MyCustomHelper` in all example types (controllers, models, views, helpers, etc.). You can narrow that down by passing a `:type` parameter:

```
config.include MyControllerHelper, :type => :controller
```

Comment: Note for an edge case: this code will be problematic in testing a Rails Engine, where you would start from `File.dirname(__FILE__)` instead of `Rails.root` since they will differ.

Comment: FYI this is include (but commented out) in the `/spec/rails_helpers.rb` file in 5.0.1.

Answer (score 32):

Include the Module you need directly in the spec file:

```
include PostsHelper
```

Comment: ad the beginning of the file

Comment: Does anyone know how to do this in a view? `<% include PostsHelper %>` produces the error `undefined method `include' for #<ActionView::Base:0x0000559478b3cf60>`…

Comment: thanks to @juliangonzalez to point out that its important to put it at beginning!

Answer (score 0):

(Rails 7) You can also extend the helpers lookup location in e.g. `application.rb` like

```
# https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-action-view
config.helpers_paths << 'path/to/unusual/helper/location.rb'
```