# How to Include Rails views helper in Capybara steps

Tags: capybara, view-helpers

I have a *step definition*:

```
Then(/^I should see the total price of the products$/) do
  # assumes all existing products are in the cart
  total = Product.find(:all).inject { |sum, p| sum + p.price }
  page.find(".total").should have_content number_to_currency(total)
end
```

This blows up with `undefined method 'number_to_currency' for #<Cucumber::Rails::World:0xbef8d18> (NoMethodError)`

I could emulate the "total" by emulating the behaviour of the `number_to_currency` helper, but I'd rather re-use the helper from Rails, because in this step I am not interested in the formatting, just that the total is calculated and rendered.

How do I include the NumberHelper or any view helper in capybara for access from step definitions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9445410/how-to-include-rails-helpers-on-rspec

Comment: Probably not: the linked Q and A are specific for rspec, yet I need to include the helpers in cucumber stepdefs;

Comment: That's fine. I didn't flag the question as I was waiting for your comment. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way I include helper into my cucumber testing here:

- You create a file world.rb (or any name you want) under support folder. In my world.rb I define like this:

  ```
  module Helper

     include ProjectHelper
     include ProductBacklogHelper
     include ApplicationHelper
     include Capybara::DSL
     include Prickle::Capybara 

  end #end Module  
  World(Helper)
  ```

You should include the helper file that has "number_to_currency" function in world.rb

I hope this will help you