# How to create cucumber (capybara?) helpers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

I a have some code I'd like to refactor out of my step definitions and put them inside.. helpers?

Oh and please also say how to *include them*, I am really having a hard time finding any solid info on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Straight from the rspec documentation here: https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/helper-methods/define-helper-methods-in-a-module#include-a-module-in-all-example-groups

Include a module in all example groups
Given a file named "include_module_spec.rb" with:

```
require './helpers'

RSpec.configure do |c|
  c.include Helpers
end

RSpec.describe "an example group" do
  it "has access to the helper methods defined in the module" do
    expect(help).to be(:available)
  end
end

When
I run rspec include_module_spec.rb
Then
the examples should all pass
```

You may also benefit from a a support/helpers folder Or equivalent which is covered pretty well here: [How to include Rails Helpers on RSpec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9445410/how-to-include-rails-helpers-on-rspec)